Number of ways of selecting $k$ out of $n$ points, arranged in a circle, such that no more than $a$ point are consecutive.
$n\geq k\geq 2$.
There are $n$ point arranged in a circle from which we have to select $k$ points, such that no more than $a$ are consecutive.
We already know the answer when we have to pick non-consecutive integers, which is, $\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}\frac{n}{k}$, but what about for $a\geq 2$? For example, lets say $n=8$, $k=5$ and $a=2$. So one way of picking $4$ points from $8$ such that no more than $2$ are consecutive are points $1,3,4,6,8$. Here the consecutive points are $3,4$ and $1,8$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
